# Where is the code that filter web and email addresses into links?

Tags: input-formats

Under full html, drupal states: "Web page addresses and e-mail addresses turn into links automatically."

I'm curious to know where this behaviour is coded and how I would hook into it if I need to modify it slightly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is for Drupal 7

You can see where the default filters are defined in [/modules/filter/filter.module line 1147](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x:/modules/filter/filter.module#l1147). There we see that [_filter_url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--filter--filter.module/function/_filter_url/7) ([line 1358](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x:/modules/filter/filter.module#l1358)) is the function used to transform text into links.

You shouldn't modify this code directly. Instead you can implement [hook_filter_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--filter--filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info_alter/7) to change the process callback for url filter to your own function (you can copy `_filter_url()` and make the few changes you need)

```
function YOURMODULE_filter_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['filter_url']['process callback'] = 'YOURMODULE_filter_url';
}
```

Keep in mind that these changes will be reflected everywhere the URL Filter is used. If you need something not so "all inclusive", you can [implement a new filter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--filter--filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7) that you can apply to a seperate input format.